# Can't add static lease from inside DHCP range in pfSense

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, pfsense

When trying to add my computer to static lease, I get the following error

[image]

I don't understand the reason for this. If I would want to assign IP from outside DHCP range, I would assign it statically locally on the device connecting. If I am assigning IP at the server, I see no reason I can't set it from inside DHCP range.

All previous routers were allowing me to assign within range.

Is it possible to turn off this "check" so that I will be able to set any address I want?

Comment: IIRC, the DHCP range in pfSense is simply the range of IP addresses automatically distributed to unrecognized clients, not the range of possible IP addresses served by the DHCP server.  Not sure why you'd want to *force* the DHCP server to run the risk of double-allocating the same IP address.  Say your range is 10.0.0.100-200 and you want to forcefully allocate 10.0.0.50; a random computer connects before yours and gets 10.0.0.50 via DHCP (which is legit, being in the range); when your computer connects, what should happen?

Comment: How is 50 inside the range of 100-200?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque you are describing a problem, which can occur if local set address. But what problem can occur if all addresses, both auto and manual, are set on server? Server knows all of them. How can this lead to any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when you set a static IP inside the DHCP Range, is that if the computer which you set the static IP is ever off line, the IP that was specified to him could be assigned to another machine. When the original computer comes on line, it will not be able to get that IP.

pfSense enforces this, but I figure you could always edit the relevant PHP file to turn this rule off. Which I don't know how to do, so anyone wanting to do this would need to do your own research.

Shouldn't be hard to do, although it's a lot easier just to either:

-> Split the DHCP Pool so it doesn't include the desired IP or;

-> Give up and just assign an IP outside of the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that remembering an IP address for a device, and excluding an address from the DHCP pool, are two different features.

For whatever reason, pfSense doesn't support excluding the address from the pool, and so does the only other sane thing, which is to prevent you assigning an address that will potentially conflict with a DHCP address it may give out to someone else in the future.